# Are there certain conditions that $a_n$ must meet in order for this series to converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose we have an alternating series of the form
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{a_n}}{n}$$
We know this converges for some basic cases, like when $a_n=n$ (the [sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MercatorSeries.html) evaluating to $-\ln2$) or for interesting alternating patterns like
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}}{n}=1+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\cdots=\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\ln2}{2}$$
I also recall seeing a question on here about an alternation resembling a factorial pattern, something like
$$1-\underbrace{\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\right)}_{2!\text{ terms}}+\underbrace{\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{9}\right)}_{3!\text{ terms}}-\cdots$$
which may or may not have converged, I cannot seem to find it...

Is there a generalization that can be made about the conditions on $a_n$ for these types of series?

Comment: I suspect a general resolution of this is a Hard Problem™.

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris No. The limit above is $1$ for any real $a_n$.

Comment: If the density of the set $\{n\colon a_n \text{ is even} \}$ exists, it must equal $\frac12$ for the series to converge. (But there are lots of sequences where that density doesn't even exist....) Even the density equaling $\frac12$ isn't sufficient, though: take $a_n=n$ for all $n$ except those of the form $2\lfloor k\log k\rfloor$ for some $k$, in which case take $a_n=-1$. Here the density equals $\frac12$ but the series diverges to $-\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you're going to find a *characterization* that's not just a disguised version of "the series converges if and only if the series converges"; convergence of this series is a *ding an sich* (sp?), seems to me.

But the series does converge for "most" choices! If $(\epsilon_n)$ is a sequence of plus or minus ones chosen "at random" then the series $\sum \epsilon_n/n$ converges almost surely.

(I was about to give a more precise statement of that, decided that would be silly; anyone with the background to understand the precise statement should be able to formulate it for himself. Regarding *proving* it, look in some probability book in the neighborhood of the Law of Large Numbers...)

Comment: I realize I made the "mistake" of over-generalizing. I have a specific set of cases I'm thinking about for $a_n$, but I'd like to think about it some more before I post another question on the topic.